# Bootstrap carousel - space on bottom with wide images

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap-3, carousel

The image is 800*450, and the problem is the one in the picture. The problem doesn't appear with (for example) 320 × 455 images
[image: Here what happen]

This is the jade code for carousel

```
.col-md-12.col-xs-12
    #header-carousel.carousel.slide(data-ride="carousel", data-interval="5000")
        .carousel-inner
            each image, i in content.images
                if i === 0
                    .item.active
                    img(src="#{image}", alt="phone")
                else
                    .item
                    img(src="#{image}", alt="phone")
        a.left.carousel-control(href="#header-carousel", data-slide="prev")
            span.icon-prev
        a.right.carousel-control(href="#header-carousel", data-slide="next")
            span.icon-next
```

Here the custom CSS

```
.carousel-inner > .item > img,
  .carousel-inner > .item > a > img {
    width: 100%;
    margin: 0 auto;
    padding: 0px !important;
}
 .carousel-control .glyphicon-chevron-left, .carousel-control     .glyphicon-chevron-right, .carousel-control .icon-prev, .carousel-control .icon-next {
  width: 100px;
  padding: 0px !important;
  margin: 0px !important;
}
```

**How to remove the grey part?**

Comment: Can you provide a jsfiddle reproducing the problem?

Comment: provide a fiddle or link for your live code deployed somewhere

Answer (score 0):

I had this issue, try to add, in the image tag, attributes for width and height of the image.
Something like this:

```
 img(src="#{image}", alt="phone", width="800", height="450")
```